# Constructing Array of Objects Confusion

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So, I'm making a program that calculates the distance given seven velocities and six angles of trajectory. Given the formula to conduct the necessary 42 operations, I must store the results in a two-dimensional array and print the results in a neat and orderly fashion.

I am having confusion on why a particular part of my program is not working. It seems alright to me, however the output is not what I was expecting because it's random and illogical. The error is the output given from the code which results in "Catapult@xxxxx...." where the "x"s represent a random series of letters, numbers, or characters. I'm not sure where they come from and why, so I would like an explanation, and how to fix this problem of mines. The source code is below:

```
static final int ROWS = 7;
static final int COLS = 6;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double[] angles = {25.0, 30.0, 35.0, 40.0, 45.0, 50.0};
    double[] rads = new double[COLS];
    for(int i = 0; i < COLS; i++)
    {
        rads[i] = Math.toRadians(angles[i]);
    }
    double[] speeds = {20.0, 25.0, 30.0, 35.0, 40.0, 45.0, 50.0};

    Catapult[][] projectile = new Catapult[ROWS][COLS];
    for(int a = 0; a < ROWS; a++)
    {
        for(int b = 0; b < COLS; b++)
        {
            projectile[a][b] = new Catapult(speeds[a], rads[b]);
        }
    }
```

If you were to type `System.out.print(projectile[a][b] + " ");` after `projectile[a][b] = new Catapult(speeds[a], rads[b]);` in the second for-loop, then it would result in the error described earlier.

Comment: You need to override `toString` in `Catapult`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but could you explain that a bit more? I'm not sure what you mean by override `toString` in `Catapult`.

Comment: That's a comment, but you're getting the default `toString` from `Object`. See [Overriding and Hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) from the Java Tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
class Catapult {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // Do here what you want to print
        return "Catapult{}";
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

*public String toString()
Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.
The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
 getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
Returns:
a string representation of the object.*

Comment: I'm not sure what that method is supposed to do. Could you explain it in-depth a bit more?

Comment: Does this method go in my main method or outside? If outside, how would I invoke this method to my main method?

Comment: It will be invoked automatically when you print out the Catapult  reference